# Add subviews to Custom UIView without using a XIB file

Tags: uiview, xamarin.ios, xamarin, flyout

I am trying to create a view class to work with the flyout navigation component.
As of yet, I have not found a way to create a view and add subview's to itself.
Here is a sample view class that I have created--note, I am not using a XIB file because I would like to avoid XCode--it has been going in and out of sync constantly.  This is simply a normal C# file that inherits UIView and attempts to create a view.  How do I add subviews to it?

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;
using FlyoutNavigation;
using MonoTouch.Dialog;

namespace Flyout
{
public class MessagesView : UIView
{
    public MessagesView ()
    {
        var field = new UITextField (new RectangleF(10f, 10f, 300f, 40f));
        field.Placeholder = "Test";
        field.BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.RoundedRect;
  // does not work  MessagesView.addSubview(field);
        var field2 = new UITextField (new RectangleF(10f, 60f, 300f, 40f));
        field2.Placeholder = "Test2";
        field2.BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.RoundedRect;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: "does not work" - what does not work when you try AddSubview?  Do you get an error?  Or is the field just not visible on the view?

Comment: have you tried this.AddSubview() instead of MessagesView.AddSubview()?  MessagesView is a class, not an instance.  And you should probably put that logic in your ViewDidAppear() method, not the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

UIView has an [AddSubview()](http://docs.go-mono.com/index.aspx?link=M%3aMonoTouch.UIKit.UIView.AddSubview%28MonoTouch.UIKit.UIView%29) method.

```
[MonoTouch.Foundation.Export("addSubview:")]
public virtual void AddSubview (UIView view)
```